# Best way to iterate in SQL table rows - C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I want to fetch each record from sql server table one by one based on identity column field as
a separate method call in C#. I want to iterate in more than 50000 rows.

for eg: I want to fetch first row from SQL table and based on row values, need to do some C# coding process. Then need to fetch the second row, so and so.

what is the best way to do this instead of maintaining a single Data reader connecttion throug out the time?

Kindly help.

Comment: you are not clear give example what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Are you try to do looping result set in the back end itself or trying to do it on front end by a data table or Dto ?

Comment: If each row in SQL Server has to do some C# logic and each row is independent of other row in SQL Server then fetch all the rows at once to your C# code (like DataSet.Load) and then process for each row rather than keeping the connection open for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using

```
`foreach (DataRow dr in Table_Name.Rows)`
{
variable1 = dr["Column1_Name"];
variable2 = dr["Column2_Name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. TEntity can be a class representing one row in your database.

```
public class MyEnumerable<TEntity> : IEnumerable<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    private Entity _lastElement;

    public IEnumerator<TEntity> GetEnumerator()
    {
        TEntity nextElement = // get next element based on _lastElement from database

        // check if a next element exists
        if (nextElement != null)
        {
            _lastElement = nextElement;
            yield return _lastElement;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But I think the performance of this would be realy bad, because for each row you have the overhead of creating/opening a connection (should be pooled by ADO.NET though) and fetching the query result.
You can use this like:

```
MyEnumerable<Entity> myEnumerable = new MyEnumerable<Entity>();
foreach (var entity in myEnumerable)
{
     // do work
}
```